# How to filter out a dataframe for participants who has a date that is before another date in the same row? (For R)

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
teamid        startdate      enddate
1              2017-07-01   2018-06-30
2              2016-07-01   2017-06-30
3              2016-07-01   2017-06-30
4              2026-07-01   2017-06-30
5              2026-07-01   2017-06-30
6              2026-07-01   2017-06-30
```

How do I filter out the date so it only includes teamid's that have the enddate to be before the startdate?

Comment: Assuming the date variables are actually dates and not just character strings, do you just want `data[data$enddate < data$startdate,]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do some little tricks on the two character vars? like:

```
library(dplyr)

df1<-read.table(text = "teamid  startdate   enddate
1   2017-07-01  2018-06-30
2   2016-07-01  2017-06-30
3   2016-07-01  2017-06-30
4   2026-07-01  2017-06-30
5   2026-07-01  2017-06-30
6   2026-07-01  2017-06-30",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)


df1$tempt.startdate<-as.numeric(gsub('-',"",df1$startdate,fixed = TRUE))
df1$tempt.enddate<-as.numeric(gsub('-',"",df1$enddate,fixed = TRUE))

df1[df1$tempt.startdate>df1$tempt.enddate,] %>%
  select(teamid,startdate,enddate)
```

and the result:

```
  teamid  startdate    enddate
4      4 2026-07-01 2017-06-30
5      5 2026-07-01 2017-06-30
6      6 2026-07-01 2017-06-30
```